# Loading real time 3D models into Kinect WPF Application

Tags: wpf

I am creating a WPF application using C# for Kinect. I am trying to load a 3D model into the application and make it mimic the user standing in front of the Kinect device. I was able to find a file dude.fbx from Microsoft and load it into my app. But unfortunately I cannot load any other 3D model into my app. It would be great if anyone out here could help me with this.

Comment: How do load the model ? Please provide some code or more explanations.